# Characterising the space where some numbers should lie

Tags: calculus

Consider a matrix $M\times T$, where $M=5$ and $T=4$.

For each $m=1,...,5$ and $t=1,...,4$, the $(m,t)$-th entry of the matrix is a letter among $a,b,c,d$.

Let us denote by $X_{m,t}$ the $(m,t)$-th entry of the matrix.

Let us define
$$
p_{a}\equiv \frac{1}{5} \ \times \Big|\Big\{m\in \{1,...,5\}: X_{m,t}=a \text{ for some } t\in \{1,...,4\} \Big\}\Big|
$$
Define similarly $p_b, p_c, p_d$.

For example, based on the example matrix below, $p_a=1, p_b=3/5, p_c=3/5, p_d=2/5$.

[image]

Observe that $p_a,p_b,p_c,p_d$ are all between 0 and 1.

**Question**: can we characterise where $p_{a}+p_b+p_c+p_d$ lies? For example, we cannot have that $p_a=0.2, p_b=0, p_c=0, p_d=0$. Also, I think $p_{a}+p_b+p_c+p_d\geq 1$.

PS: please feel free to change/suggest tags, I'm not sure which one is the right one.

Comment: If in each row you add the number of *different* letters, and divide this by $5$, you get $p_a+p_b+p_c+p_d$. Thus, that sum can be at least $1$ (every row has a single letter, e.g. $p_a=2/5, p_b=p_c=p_d=1/5$) and at most $4$ (every row has all letters, i.e. $p_a=p_b=p_c=p_d=1$).

Comment: Thanks: the upper bound equal to 4 comes from $T=4$ or the fact that I have 4 letter options?

Comment: Whatever is the smaller of the two, it seems.